# Sending a custom status back from a jQuery .load()

Tags: jquery

After getting a bunch of image names back from a .load() call to the server, I'd like to know how many image names were sent to me. Is there a way that the PHP on the server can write that number where the .load completion routine at the client can see it?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly does the server return? Does it return a plain-text list of image URLs?

Comment: It echoes a bunch of HTML, basically building a table with img tags in the td elements.  I could have it echo the number of images at the end, I guess, but then I'd have to look through the Response for it. I just thought there might be a way to write the status field directly that comes back from the call.

Answer (score 0):

```
$.post('ajax/test.html', function(data) {
  var count = data.match(/<img/g);
  alert("images: " + count.length);

  $("#element").html(data);
});
```

This script counts how many times the tag  exists in the response, then append the data to element with id="element".

Comment: Yeah, ok.  I noticed that the .load() success completion callback is passed response, status, and xhr and I thought I might be able to set the status field to some custom text at the server. No?